# What is the terminology for a phrase whose common usage is diametrically opposite to its literal meaning?

Tags: phrase-usage

For example, consider the following simple phrases one typically says upon entering a popular restaurant:

- `I love chicken.`
- `I love fish.`

If the person *literally* loves fish, he/she wouldn't really want to take its life and eat it. What they really mean to say is `I love cutting and eating a fish`.

Does this come under *Irony*? But Irony is generally a deliberate attempt to reverse a meaning for creating humor.

Comment: Can you provide us with another example?

Comment: @LittleEva I found one from this [Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10571/what-are-non-ironic-english-expressions-used-with-a-meaning-opposite-to-their-li) - `The alarm goes off when an intruder enters the house.`. *Going off* actually means going silent which is the opposite of what happens when it starts ringing.

Comment: *I love chicken* is not the same as *I love chickens*.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Ridiculous amount": semantic change (amelioration) originated from an antiphrasis? When and how?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144654/ridiculous-amount-semantic-change-amelioration-originated-from-an-antiphras)

Comment: These are not opposites; they are coincidental special cases. Consider "I love pork" versus "I love pigs."

Comment: @PrahladYeri - no, an alarm *going off* is when it activates. **turning off** is when it deactivates.

Comment: @Oldcat Exactly! *Going off* should not mean *activates*, because *off* indicates something being deactivated.

Comment: No, _off_ by itself indicates about 500 different things. When used with the verb _go_, it doesn’t mean ‘deactivate’. Alarms go off; guns go off; things that start moving go off; people that start talking and ranting go off; food goes off. _Go off_ never means ‘deactivate’, except inasmuch as you consider rotten food to be ‘deactivated food’.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If one word means its opposite, it's called an [autantonym or contronym](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/autoantonym).

What you are referring to is called [polysemy](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Polysemy):

> (from Greek: πολυ-, poly-, "many" and σῆμα, sêma, "sign") is the capacity for a sign (e.g., a word, phrase, etc.) or signs to have multiple related meanings (sememes), i.e., a large semantic field. It is usually regarded as distinct from homonymy, in which the multiple meanings of a word may be unconnected or unrelated.
>
> Charles Fillmore and Beryl Atkins’ definition stipulates three elements: (i) the various senses of a polysemous word have a central origin, (ii) the links between these senses form a network, and (iii) understanding the ‘inner’ one contributes to understanding of the ‘outer’ one.

**Love** can be used reasonably and accurately with both versions you give, because language is more than the sum of its parts. Love is much more than one thing, though one word can be used.

> - I *love* fish. I have raised tropical saltwater fish for 12 years now.
> - I *love* fish. The light, flaky texture and delicate flavor of (favorite fish here) beats steak any day!

*Verbal irony* is something different. After the Charlie Hebdo attack, verbal irony was everywhere, as in this cartoon.

[image]

Edited to add: OP's comment is an example of contronym:

> [Contronyms](http://forward.com/articles/3132/the-curious-contronym/) ...do not tend to cause confusion, as it is generally clear from their grammatical or semantic context which of their two meanings is intended. In the sentence “He buckled,” for example, we know that the subject collapsed, since in its sense of “to fasten,” the verb is transitive and must be followed by a direct object; similarly, in the two grammatically identical sentences, “The house weathered the storms” and “The storms weathered the house,” simple logic tells us what “weathered” means in each case. Yet there can certainly be instances — e.g., “The horse had a handicap” — in which a contronymic sentence is interpretable in opposite ways.

<sub>Till a' the seas gang dry, my dear,/And the rocks melt wi' the sun;/And I will **luve** thee still, my dear,/While the sands o' life shall run.</sub>

Comment: @medica You seem to be suggesting that the polysemy here is present in the word *love*, but I think that in both cases *I love X* equates to *X gives me pleasure*. Isn't the polysemy to be found rather in the word *fish* (*a fish* [countable] = an aquatic vertebrate / *fish* [uncountable] = the flesh of aquatic verterbrates)? There's the same polysemy in *chicken*, but unlike for *fish*, the OP's *I love chicken* doesn't really have two alternative meanings, since the plural of [countable] *chicken* is *chickens* with an *s*.

Comment: @LachlanDominic - Nice point. Love (eros, agape, etc) does have different meanings, not all of which mean "give me pleasure" (one hopes, at least). However, is *fish* polysemy? Maybe! It's a bit like that *Twilight Zone* when the aliens had that book, *How to Serve Man*. (It wasn't about selflessness.) There, *serve* was polysemy.

Comment: @medica Excellent observation! I stand by my *fish* [C] vs *fish* [UC], but I ought to brush up on my Greek before throwing a word like *polysemy* around with such abandon.

Comment: +1 _Polysemy_ it is. Moreover, there is a specific type of polysemy involved here which is "systematic polysemy" (also called _count-mass polysemy_ for this specific example). Further reading: http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/1139079/1/1139079.pdf

Comment: the autantonym link is very interesting, especially the examples list. I am realising how weird the word "off" is.

Answer (score 1):

These could loosely be a type of **solecism**, but the examples you gave happen to be special cases that don't demonstrate what I think you mean to demonstrate.

A better example would be the word "literally." People started using it for emphasis even when it wasn't true, and then it got to the point where it was so overused that people started using it in place of "figuratively," which of course means exactly the opposite. This particular solecism is a linguistic scourge among young women in the US.

> Buzzfeed is literally my life

and

> I would literally kill for a frappucino

Answer (score -4):

It is known as a "common error".  Another good example is the word inflammable.

As in:  "Don't worry it says this liquid is inflammable."  The common error is that inflammable is not the opposite of flammable, it is the same as.

Comment: *Inflammable* is not an error, it's the originally used word. It comes from the same root as *inflame*, not as an antonym of *flammable*. The switch to *flammable* mostly happened in the 20th century, to avoid this sort of confusion.