# "Owe" and "own" sound similar but have nearly opposite meanings

Tags: etymology

You can own a beer, or you can owe someone a beer. These are approximately opposite statements of your wealth (in beer).

I can see some references that both are "From Middle English owen, from Old English āgan" ([owe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/owe#Etymology), [own](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/own#Etymology_1)) but that doesn't really explain how the modern words came to be as they are.

Since "owe" and "own" share a common root or origin, how did they come to have such a distinction?

Comment: Because English.

Comment: Wait till you meet 'sanction'.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324360/what-is-the-term-for-a-word-which-has-the-meaning-changed-to-its-opposite

Comment: @marcellothearcane wait till you meet [all the other ones](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_contranyms).

Comment: Wait till you take your first course in double-entry bookkeeping :)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the etymology of the Old English [āgan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agan#Old_English) that both words derive from, it seems that at that time it could mean either to own, or to cause someone else to own. Thus "I āgan a beer" - I own a beer, it belongs to me. "I āgan you a beer" - I will make you own a beer, I will make this beer belong to you. The words aren't all that different, then - "I owe you a beer" is basically similar to "I will make you own a beer".